# How to call a java class in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

just started learning selenium-webdriver and trying too....soo here is my dout?

**below created a function navigate to google home page**

```
 
package UtilityGoogle;
```

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class HomePage {
     WebDriver WD=null;

`public static void main(WebDriver WD) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WD = new FirefoxDriver();
    WD.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in");
    WD.manage().window().maximize();

    return;
}`

**and below code calling Homepage function..**

```js
package GoogleMain;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import UtilityGoogle.HomePage;

public class Google_Tc1 {
  private static WebDriver XP = null;@
  Test
  public void Open() {
    HomePage HP = new HomePage();
    String actual = XP.getTitle();
    String expected = "Google";
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

}
```

Getting below error .... please do help me to fix this

```html
FAILED: Open
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at GoogleMain.Google_Tc1.Open(Google_Tc1.java:13)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class GoogleTest {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void Open() {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        String actual = driver.getTitle();
        String expected = "Google";
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the WebDriver to `null` here:

```
private static WebDriver XP = null;
```

Then in your `Open()` method try to use it:

```
String actual = XP.getTitle();
```

The stack trace informs you of this:

```
at GoogleMain.Google_Tc1.Open(Google_Tc1.java:13)
```

So to fix it assign `XP`

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebDriver XP` instrance variable is never initialized. The `main` method in `HomePage` is never called, and even if it was it wouldn't matter since it doesn't manipulate the `XP` variable you're trying to use on your test.

I believe this is what you want to achieve:

```
public class HomePage {

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

And the test class:

```
public class GoogleTest {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void Open() {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        String actual = driver.getTitle();
        String expected = "Google";
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

Now when you create an instance of `HomePage` passing a driver as an argument, the driver is initialized and can be used.

I changed the variable names because the names you used weren't good. You should read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf). I also think there are room for a lot of other improvements. You should probably read about the Page Object Model [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) and [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) and try to stick with it.

Comment: First of all thanks @ThiagoPorciúncula quick reply, so iam struggling to fix on below mark for code 'HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver)' 

**Multiple markers at this line 
-The constructor HomePage(WebDriver) is undefined 
-Watchpoint:Google_Tc1 [access and modification] 
- driver**

Answer (score 0):

Just like you have initialized WD in main method of Homepage class,`WD = new FirefoxDriver();`
similarly you have to initialize XP before using it.

```js
package GoogleMain;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import UtilityGoogle.HomePage;

public class Google_Tc1 {
  private static WebDriver XP = new FirefoxDriver();@
  Test
  public void Open() {
    HomePage HP = new HomePage();
    String actual = XP.getTitle();
    String expected = "Google";
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

}
```

Comment: First of all thanks @Sourabh quick reply, so iam struggling to fix on below mark for code 'private static WebDriver XP = new FirefoxDriver();' 


**Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor HomePage(WebDriver) is 
  undefined
 - Watchpoint:Google_Tc1 [access and modification] 
  - driver**